# What is a cheap puncture-proof tire against tackweed?

Tags: road-bike, tire, commuter, innertube, puncture

Lately, each time I ride my bike around the Bay Area, I get tackweed onto my wheels where upon one or both of them flatten overnight. Most of those are five minute rides to my local library. So, I have had to replace the tube at least ten times already for a two-month period. Details of the situation:

1. Road Bike that I got from Costco.
2. Tire is 700x40c, Kenda (42-622)

I'm not very verse in bicycles, but my final solution is that I need to find a tire that does not get punctured by tackweed. My problem is that I have not found such tires at a cheap price with the right size. By cheap price, I mean something around $25-30 if able; otherwise, I would alright with something less than $70 as long as the size can be fitted onto the rim.

[image: Each intertube replacement for one wheel is $20-$25.]

Comment: You could try (in decreasing order of appeal) kevlar belted tires, thornproof tubes, slimed tubes (messy) or tire liners (high rolling resistance, can cause more flats if put in wrong). All of these options are discussed in other questions as well as here: http://sheldonbrown.com/flats.html. You can also go to your LBS and get a tire recommendation there for something which works well in your area (if it is a problem, certainly a lot of other people in the bay area have had it).

Comment: Unfortunately there's no such thing as puncture-proof. There's puncture-resistant, but this generally equates to fancier materials and higher costs. As @Batman says, Kevlar belts (not Kevlar beads, that's something different and won't help you) are generally an improvement, but the problem you might have is finding something that fits your budget.

Comment: Yeah, Kevlar belted is probably your best bet.  Unfortunately, they're a little hard to find in such a wide size, and the wider they are the more expensive they are.  Continental Gatorskins in a 32mm are $45.  The other major puncture-resistant design uses a fairly thick plastic belt under the tread which may be as effective as Kevlar but adds rolling resistance.

Answer (score 2):

Forget the slime, thornproof tubes, and tire liners.  IMO, the best puncture protection for under $40 are Vittoria Randonneurs.  I've had excellent luck with them.  I had a pair of Gatorskins before the Randonneurs, and trust me, Kevlar belts *do not* work as well.  Because the Kevlar is a woven material, very sharp objects can penetrate between the Kevlar fibers.  Happened to me at least six times with the Gatorskins over a two year period.  Blackberry thorns, glass, and even staples penetrated the Kevlar.

Also, since you say you're not very versed in bikes, I have to wonder if you may be pinching the tubes when mounting them, or leaving whatever punctured the tube in the tire, allowing the next tube to be punctured as well.  Are you checking for any sharp objects poking through the inside of the tire, or for any burrs along the inside of the rim?  I always try to find the puncture in the tube *before* removing it from the rim, so I can concentrate on that area of the tire for a closer inspection.

Comment: I am certain that all of my holes are not due to me puncturing them on accident. I can find the thorn or tackweed that caused the tire to be flatten, and whenever I do pump my new tires, I do not ride my bike for a day or two. The tire is still firm until I ride into those insidious tackweeds.
 
P.S. When I said that I am not versed in bikes, I mean that I do not know much terminology on the subject of bicycles. Otherwise, I can make a bike frame out of cardboard.

P.S.S. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer. I would vote you up, but I do not have the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the Schwalbe Marathon Plus (http://www.schwalbetires.com/node/4316, [http://www.amazon.com/Schwalbe-Marathon-Plus-Tour-Allround/dp/B00516DE3S/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1398380562&sr=8-4&keywords=schwalbe+marathon+plus+28](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00516DE3S)). This does not seem to be available in 42 mm width, but only in 40 (width is the first number in 40-622, the diameter of the rim the second). But that should work. However, it is slightly more expensive than your limit of 40$.